# Windows Store UWP: ApplicationContentUriRule with 'all' or 'allowForWebOnly'

Tags: windows, windows-10-universal

My Windows 10 universal app is failing windows store certification and throwing me this error:

"The Application cannot include an ApplicationContentUriRule with 'all' or 'allowForWebOnly' WindowsRuntimeAccess while any of the following capabilities are enabled: enterpriseAuthentication, sharedUserCertificates, musicLibrary, picturesLibrary, videosLibrary, removableStorage, documentLibrary, internetClientServer, privateNetworkClientServer."

Totally have no idea what the issue is. Earlier this week I uploaded the same app and it passed certification. This is a cordova app and by default cordova adds this content uri rule:

```
<uap:Rule Match="ms-appx-web:///" Type="include" WindowsRuntimeAccess="all" />
```

Any help would be most appreciated!!

Comment: I met same problem. Can anyone solve this?

Comment: In my case, I can resolve this by using local mode instead of remote mode. My app is so simple, only xhr access the private network. Therefore I add `<preference name="WindowsDefaultUriPrefix" value="ms-appx://" />` on `config.xml`.

Comment: I have the same problem as outline [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/6d7a5c6b-8416-4da5-982c-bd77cafad30d/store-certification-failure-for-cordova-uwp-app-the-application-cannot-include-an?forum=wpsubmit). I have set the above in local mode, but still rejected from the store. Has anyone found a solutuon? This a complete nightmare. Is Cordova supported properly in UWP?

Answer (score 0):

All these restrictions are described on the "[Windows 10 for Cordova](https://github.com/apache/cordova-windows/blob/master/cordova-windows10.md)" page.

Comment: This does not provide a solution to the problem